# What can be reason for slow content downloading from webserver?

Tags: performance, nginx, webserver

I'm trying to increase performance of webpage. I'm using ReactJS + webpack, which compiles my jsx files into one file - search.bundle.js. And server is returning this file for 2-3 seconds. File size is ~200KB. Is file size the only reason? 
On local server it works pretty well. But on remote webserver it is really slow..
There is Google Map and listing of items on page, which I get using ajax request. This is recursive request (while not get enough data, or timeout) which is called in componentDidMount, but as I understand it can't because it can start request items only after script is loaded on page.

So is there any way to achive more faster downloading this script? Or I should just try to reduce size of script?

[image: This is examples of how it works now]

And some data from headers tab:

on local:

[image: local headers]

on remote:

[image: remote headers]

Comment: What Webserver are you using? Could it be, you are using on your local Webserver GZIP, but on the remote one not?

Comment: @StefanRein there is nginx, on local I use wamp (apache)

Comment: okay, what about GZIP? On Wamp it's standardly enabled. On nginx it's a module.
Is this Header on the response header: Content-Encoding:gzip
You can also show the content encoding on the Network tab (right click on the names like Name, Status, Type, Size etc.)

Comment: @StefanRein yes, there is content-endcoding gzip

Comment: @StefanRein I have added some screenshots about header information

Comment: Seems fine to me. Of course locally you have much more speed for download unless you throttle it. Since it's gzipped 200kb you could decrease the size of the file further with minifying. Your normal visitors will have caching enabled. So after downloading this file once, it will be cached.
Just uncheck the "Disable cache" checkbox and see yourself, it will be loaded locally and the "speed goes up".

Comment: @StefanRein ok, thank you

Comment: @Alexey Have you tracked down the problem? I have the same, extremely slow content download for a single script, rest are ok

Answer (score 1):

The answer to this question is that script has a source map available. With Chrome's Developer Tools panel open, it makes transparent requests to any available source map files ([which it does not show you](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=362913#c21)).

These files are often absolutely massive (mine are 3MB+) and take considerable time to pull on every refresh. Nginx specifically also handles them very poorly, at least in my setup. I think setting the max sendfile chunk size to be lower helps.